ahref with "ms-word:ofe|u" is opening document with restriction from web.xml with webdav
HTML used for ahref with "ms-word:ofe|u" :
<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|http://localhost:8080/FBAuthentication/webdav/webdavFile/TestingwebDav.docx">Open Doc</a>

Below is the web.xml:
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/webdavFile/*</url-pattern> 
        <url-pattern>/webdav/*</url-pattern> 
         <http-method>GETLIB</http-method>
         <http-method>COPY</http-method>
         <http-method>MOVE</http-method>
         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
         <http-method>PROPFIND</http-method>
         <http-method>GET</http-method>
         <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
         <http-method>MKCOL</http-method>
         <http-method>PROPPATCH</http-method>
         <http-method>LOCK</http-method>
         <http-method>UNLOCK</http-method>
         <http-method>VERSION-CONTROL</http-method>
         <http-method>CHECKIN</http-method>
         <http-method>CHECKOUT</http-method>
         <http-method>UNCHECKOUT</http-method>
         <http-method>REPORT</http-method>
         <http-method>UPDATE</http-method>
         <http-method>CANCELUPLOAD</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
  </login-config>

When opening file directly through browser putting url it ask for userID and password as digest security mentioned in web.xml.
But when opening file from "msword:ofe" it is not asking userid and password, digest security not working, file is getting open without userid and password:
ms-word:ofe|u|http://localhost:8080/FBAuthentication/webdav/webdavFile/TestingwebDav.docx

